# Retrieve secrets from AWS Secrets Manager in Node.js

Tags: node.js, aws-secrets-manager

Trying to retrieve data from secret manager using Node.js usign async / await.

using function
for example `fetchSecret('SECRETKEY')`

```
var aws = require("aws-sdk");
var client = new aws.SecretsManager({
    region: 'ap-southeast-1' // Your region
});
var secret, decodedBinarySecret;
//context.callbackWaitsForEmptyEventLoop = false;
exports.handler = (event, context, callback) => {
    client.getSecretValue({
        SecretId: 'MyFirstSecret'
    }, function(err, data) {
        if (err) {
            if (err.code === 'DecryptionFailureException')
                // Secrets Manager can't decrypt the protected secret text using the provided KMS key.
                // Deal with the exception here, and/or rethrow at your discretion.
                throw err;
            else if (err.code === 'InternalServiceErrorException')
                // An error occurred on the server side.
                // Deal with the exception here, and/or rethrow at your discretion.
                throw err;
            else if (err.code === 'InvalidParameterException')
                // You provided an invalid value for a parameter.
                // Deal with the exception here, and/or rethrow at your discretion.
                throw err;
            else if (err.code === 'InvalidRequestException')
                // You provided a parameter value that is not valid for the current state of the resource.
                // Deal with the exception here, and/or rethrow at your discretion.
                throw err;
            else if (err.code === 'ResourceNotFoundException')
                // We can't find the resource that you asked for.
                // Deal with the exception here, and/or rethrow at your discretion.
                throw err;
        } else {
            // Decrypts secret using the associated KMS CMK.
            // Depending on whether the secret is a string or binary, one of these fields will be populated.
            if ('SecretString' in data) {
                secret = data.SecretString;
            } else {
                let buff = new Buffer(data.SecretBinary, 'base64');
                decodedBinarySecret = buff.toString('ascii');
            }
        }
// Your code goes here. 
        console.log(secret);
    });
};
```

Tried
[how do I use aws secret manager with nodejs lambda](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57618689/how-do-i-use-aws-secret-manager-with-nodejs-lambda)
[Setting Secrets from AWS Secrets manager in Node.JS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58675064/setting-secrets-from-aws-secrets-manager-in-node-js)

Answer (score 0):

Again. Although you are using callbacks your code it is still async. So you should change your lambda function for async.

You could also go promisifying the .getSecretValue by doing:
`return new Promise((resolve, reject)=>  getSecretValue(...resolve())` but **AWS** comes with a `promise()` function that does that for you.
With that in mind lest improve your code a little bit.

1 - Making it async
2 - Putting into a async context

```
var aws = require("aws-sdk");
var client = new aws.SecretsManager({
    region: 'ap-southeast-1' // Your region
});
var secret, decodedBinarySecret;

//changes - async keyword
exports.handler = async (event, context) => {

const secretValue =  client.getSecretValue({ SecretId: 'MyFirstSecret' }).promise()

return secretValue
 .then((data)=>{

  // Decrypts secret using the associated KMS CMK.
  // Depending on whether the secret is a string or binary, one of these fields will be populated.
    if ('SecretString' in data) {
                secret = data.SecretString;
     } else {
                let buff = new Buffer(data.SecretBinary, 'base64');
                decodedBinarySecret = buff.toString('ascii');
     }
  // Your code goes here. 
  console.log(secret);


}).catch(err=> {

            if (err.code === 'DecryptionFailureException')
                // Secrets Manager can't decrypt the protected secret text using the provided KMS key.
                // Deal with the exception here, and/or rethrow at your discretion.
                throw err;
            else if (err.code === 'InternalServiceErrorException')
                // An error occurred on the server side.
                // Deal with the exception here, and/or rethrow at your discretion.
                throw err;
            else if (err.code === 'InvalidParameterException')
                // You provided an invalid value for a parameter.
                // Deal with the exception here, and/or rethrow at your discretion.
                throw err;
            else if (err.code === 'InvalidRequestException')
                // You provided a parameter value that is not valid for the current state of the resource.
                // Deal with the exception here, and/or rethrow at your discretion.
                throw err;
            else if (err.code === 'ResourceNotFoundException')
                // We can't find the resource that you asked for.
                // Deal with the exception here, and/or rethrow at your discretion.
                throw err;
 
})
  
};
```

Comment: Thanx .  Tried but failed exports.handler = async (event, context) => {  console.log("test") ... . There is no o/p . Any suggestion

Comment: Have even tried this one https://blog.datanextsolutions.com/working-with-aws-secret-manager-4896a1cb05d7 but it gives credential error

Comment: What is o/p ? Could you show me what is the error exactly ?

Comment: Link what i had shared gives "CredentialError" , Code shared by you or in question does not give any o/p

Comment: If i am trying code provided by AWS in javascript section it gives me 502 Bad gateway error. We access AWS on base of role. Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 0):

To connect your AWS secret manager, you need to install the SDK ie. aws-sdk

```
import { SecretsManager } from 'aws-sdk';
```

Code to fetch the secret values from the AWS secret manager.

```
let SecretsManagerClient = new SecretsManager(
                           { region: 'YOUR_SECRET_MANAGER_REGION'});

const SecretsManagerResult = await SecretsManagerClient
                            .getSecretValue({
                                SecretId: 'YOUR_SECRET_MANAGER_KEY',
                             })
                            .promise();
```

SecretsManagerClient().getSecretValue() will return data so you need to parse this data as.

```
const SecretsManagerResponse = JSON.parse(SecretsManagerResult.SecretString);
const {clsa_key, clsa_secret} = SecretsManagerResponse;
```

Thanks